# Passing a file as a parameter for a Spring web service via Postman

Tags: spring, spring-boot, postman

I am creating a Spring REST web service for someone who got a client which will use my web service. I have installed the `Postman` client to test the web service.

One of the web service's parameters is defined as follows:

```
@RequestParam(value="param2", required=true) MultipartFile param2
```

I am able to pass strings to the web service but how can I pass a file as a parameter for the web service using Postman? The problem is that many examples I've seen instructing how to do it, had an option to choose a file in the request builder in the form tab. However, in my case there's for some reason a seperate tab for the form and the files and I'm not sure how to give the file I upload a key and add it to the POST parameters.

Comment: How did you catch binary file from postman to spring boot controller's method?

Comment: @SubhaBhowmik Sorry but I don't have that code anymore

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of different ways depending on the type:

1) As form-data

[image]

2) As binary

[image]

Comment: OK it seems like I installed an "Advanced REST client" through POSTMAN which is something different than POSTMAN itself. After using POSTMAN it was all good.